# Populate DropDownList in Footer Template c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need **populate** one **DropDownList** in the **Footer Template** of my **GridView**.

The tutorial is :

http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-populate-dropdownlist-based-on-another-dropdownlist-inside-a-gridview/

I've tried using this solution without success, because the error is:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set
to an instance of an object.
```

In this line of *code-behind*:

```
area.SelectedValue = drv["area"].ToString();
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Here is my code:

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        DropDownList area = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("area");
        area.DataTextField = "area";
        area.DataValueField = "area";
        area.DataSource = RetrieveCategories();
        area.DataBind();
        area.SelectedValue = drv["area"].ToString();
    }


private DataTable RetrieveCategories()
{
    sql = " SELECT DISTINCT area FROM doTable; ";

    DataTable dtCategories = new DataTable();

    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
       new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        myConnectionString.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
        {
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dtCategories);
        }
    }
    return dtCategories;
}
```

Comment: There are not data items for Header and Footer rows, therefore `drv` is null in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, I need change tutorial?

Comment: You have already changed it. What applies to DataRow type of rows in GridView might not apply to Footer. That is precisely your case - tutorial works with DataRow (for which DataItem makes sense and is not null), while you are trying to work with Footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `drv` object doesn't have any data (null) since it is in the footer.  The grid is bound and all data is linked to the grid rows, the footer has nothing since it there regardless of number of rows of data.

If you need something from the data in one of the rows I suggest making a global variable and assign it while binding the row data.  Then once your footer bind happens the value will be available in the global var that you assigned.

eg:

```
// Create global *NOT* in your binding method
private string _area = "";


// Then in your binding method change it to read the row data assuming this is
// where you want to get the area from.
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    area = drv["area"].ToString();
}
else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
    // your other code here...
    // then replace the assignment
    area.SelectedValue = _area;
}
```